# Need assistance with React, removing one component from a specific react page, not all of them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

As the title, I need some help with my code. I want to remove: Navbar and SimpleButtons from /Login and /CreatePage but not the rest of the pages listed. this is my App.jsx:

Hi guys. As the title, I need some help with my code. I want to remove: Navbar and SimpleButtons from /Login and /CreatePage but not the rest of the pages listed. this is my App.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
//Import Libraries
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'

//Import CSS
import './App.css'

//Import Components
import SimpleButtons from './components/Buttons'
//Import Pages
import ChatPage from './pages/ChatPage';
import ActivityPage from './pages/ActivityPage';
import SearchPage from './pages/SearchPage';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import CreatePage from './pages/CreateAccountPage';
import Upload from './pages/UploadPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Navbar/>
      <SimpleButtons/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={SearchPage}/>
        <Route exact path="/Login" component={LoginPage}/>
        <Route exact path="/SearchPage" component={SearchPage}  />
        <Route exact path="/CreatePage" component={CreatePage}  />
        <Route exact path="/Chat" component={ChatPage}  />
        <Route exact path="/Activity" component={ActivityPage}  />
        <Route exact path="/UploadPage" component={Upload}  /> 
      </Switch> 
      <Footer/>
    </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

On your app you can add an statement check, something like:

```
{ route === "/Login" || route === "/CreatePage" ? null : (<Navbar/>
<SimpleButtons/>)}
```